# Renderscript broken with AndroidX?

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

Since I've migrated to androidx I can't make Renderscript run. I'm getting following exception:

> 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328 27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64:
>   java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI
>   NewGlobalRef called with pending exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/pl.qus.xenoamp2-xHJAddeg9oM-uGSxlvMp7A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/pl.qus.xenoamp2-xHJAddeg9oM-uGSxlvMp7A==/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/pl.qus.xenoamp2-xHJAddeg9oM-uGSxlvMp7A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a,
>   /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]] 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   java.lang.Class
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String)
>   (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String,
>   boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String)
>   (ClassLoader.java:312) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:-2) 2018-10-12
>   16:27:58.328 27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64:
>   java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.String
>   java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)
>   (Runtime.java:1099) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(java.lang.ClassLoader,
>   java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:1014) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:1657)
>   2018-10-12 16:27:58.328 27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64:
>   java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.internalCreate(android.content.Context,
>   int, androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType, int)
>   (RenderScript.java:1408) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context,
>   int, androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType, int)
>   (RenderScript.java:1599) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context,
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType, int)
>   (RenderScript.java:1549) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context,
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript$ContextType)
>   (RenderScript.java:1525) 2018-10-12 16:27:58.328
>   27195-27195/pl.qus.xenoamp2 A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
>   androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(android.content.Context)
>   (RenderScript.java:1512)

I have usual entries in gradle:

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Anything else I have to change?

Comment: I'm also having issues with renderscript... it crashes my app with a fatal signal11 pre API21

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same issue, i switched to non support version of renderscript

In project gradle

```
renderscriptTargetApi 17
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false
```

And in the class that use renderscript

```
import android.renderscript.RenderScript
```

instead of

```
import androidx.renderscript.RenderScript
```

It did the job for me but i don't like this solution, to be completed

Comment: This solved it for me as well, it was crashing on API 21 before. renderscriptTargetApi can be at least the same as your minSdkVersion though I think.

Comment: Strange! Seems only broken with AndroidX. Works like a charm with the legacy support library

Comment: What do you miss out on by turning renderscriptSupportMode off?

Comment: Guys, I've kinda found a problem with this. It seems that changing from the support libraries (android.support.v8.renderscript) to the regular renderscript libraries (android.renderscript.RenderScript), removes 64-bit compatibility. This means your app will no longer be supported by 1 Aug on the playstore for 64 bit phones. Has anyone found a solution for this???

Comment: @Zee it seems that you need bump your `renderscriptTargetApi` to 21 or later to get 64-bit support - https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#renderscript-and-64-bit

Comment: Where can I find androidx.renderscript.RenderScript? Which androidx artifact contains it as I was not able to find it on packages reference list https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/packages

Comment: Worked for me, set renderscriptTargetApi = minSdkVersion = 21. renderscriptSupportModeEnabled = false. App was crashing on API21 aswell. Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There was an issue with the build tools (the prebuilt librsjni_androidx.so, to be exact), and is now fixed in version **29.0.2**.

I've verified this by upgrading compile sdk to API 29 and build tools to 29.0.2.

Edit:
This is what I've configured in `build.gradle`:

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Comment: what is your default config like? are you using renderscriptTargetApi 21 renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true?

Comment: @dtunctuncer hey I've edited the answer to include my configs in build.gradle:         
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

Comment: thanks man I will try it I hope it won't introduce new crashes :)

Answer (score 5):

in my gradle module file I had:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 19
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

And, I had the following imports before migrating to AndroidX:

```
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Element;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Matrix4f;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3;
```

After migrating to AndroidX, just like the documentation says:

I kept the same statements on my gradle module file, but I upgraded to buildToolsVersion 29.0.2 and my compileSdkVersion to 28

I changed the previous imports to the following, and it all works.

```
import androidx.renderscript.Matrix4f;
import androidx.renderscript.RenderScript;
import androidx.renderscript.Allocation;
import androidx.renderscript.Element;
import androidx.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import androidx.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix;
import androidx.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3;
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the version of `buildToolsVersion` to `29.0.2` and `renderscriptTargetApi` to `29`:

```
android {
    // ...
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        renderscriptTargetApi 29
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: YAY! This works :) also checked and it does not cause the bit 64 issue.

Comment: Wait, it still crashes on Android 6 :( sigh. Does anyone actually have a solution for this?

Comment: There was no need to update `renderscriptTargetApi`  to 29 in my case. I have set it to 19, while I use RS features from 21. Updating `buildToolsVersion` and also updating the pro-guard rules worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed by adding proguard:
I got answer from google supporter [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119582492#comment12)

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
native <methods>;
}
# RenderScript to be safe on "native callback" side
-keep class androidx.renderscript.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer does make it work, but as @Zee mentioned, it seems that the non-support regular renderscript removes 64-bit compatibility. Now I got a warning message from Google Play console about it when trying to publish my app. So I guess if we are still using renderscript, we will have to stay with support version and not migrate to AndroidX for now.

Comment: I published an app (closed alpha) in Google Play with RenderScript **without support mode** and I got no warnings. But I did notice the filesize is about 2MB smaller, and the `Native platforms` in Google Play are listed as `None`. With support mode enabled, there were 4 (`arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64`).

Comment: ok setting renderscriptSupportModeEnabled to false does the trick (I think) for the Android 6 issue and then having renderscriptTargetApi on 22 solves the 64 bit issue. But after all that, we still get a crash on Xiomi Redmi Go (android 8.1 ???). Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    //...
    defaultConfig {
        //...

        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: @vakio: Why isn’t it an answer? It would be more _useful_ with an explanation, and especially to differentiate it from existing answers, but it looks like an answer to me.

Comment: The templates to choose from when reviewing are not always 100% in line with what the problem is. It is an answer, but not a complete answer. And there are similar answers so it would be helpful if there was an explanation as to why this answer is different

Comment: I´m providing what is necessary to fix your error, so if you have question, please let me know it, so for this error especially place the code to your gradle  file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing that worked for me (after trying some of these), was updating to the latest build tools version (29.0.3) which I'm not sure existed when these question was originally posted:

```
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
```