# Android App stopped working pre API 21 after migration to androidx

Tags: android, crash, migration, androidx

I've migrated our project to androidx, and now the app runs on API 21 and above but doesn't work below that. The app is using multidexing and has been using it before, which was working fine. Now I simply get a fatal signal 11 and no more useful logs when the app crashes. It still works fine on API 21 and above. Do you have any clue or hint how I could get closer to resolving this issue ?

```
10-19 15:16:01.024 11813-11813/com.mycompany.myproduct /libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 11813 ()
10-19 15:16:01.964 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzcc.cancel
10-19 15:16:01.964 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.job.JobScheduler', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzcc.zzen
10-19 15:16:01.984 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService', referenced from method com.evernote.android.job.JobApi.isSupported
10-19 15:16:01.984 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService', referenced from method com.evernote.android.job.JobApi.isSupported
10-19 15:16:01.984 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.evernote.android.job.v21.PlatformJobService', referenced from method com.evernote.android.job.JobApi.isSupported
10-19 15:16:01.994 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl', referenced from method androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.onCreate
10-19 15:16:02.014 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.NotificationChannel', referenced from method io.intercom.android.sdk.push.SystemNotificationManager.setUpNotificationChannels
10-19 15:16:02.104 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
10-19 15:16:02.104 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
10-19 15:16:02.104 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets
10-19 15:16:02.104 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.removeOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
10-19 15:16:02.114 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$1', referenced from method androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener
10-19 15:16:02.804 11979-11979/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
10-19 15:16:02.804 11979-11979/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
10-19 15:16:03.104 2366-2734/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
10-19 15:16:03.354 11902-11902/com.mycompany.myproduct A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 11902 ()



buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-plugin:9.3.4'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'




repositories {
    maven() {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/intercom/intercom-maven'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        //checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myproduct"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 28
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

        testOptions {
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "bool", "branch_test", "false"
            resValue "string", "intercom_gcm_sender_id", "xxx"
        }
        debug {
            resValue "bool", "branch_test", "true"
            resValue "string", "intercom_gcm_sender_id", "xxx"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
        disable 'RestrictedApi'

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def paging_version = "2.0.0"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    releaseImplementation project(':library')
    debugImplementation project(':library')
    releaseImplementation project(':countrypicker')
    debugImplementation project(':countrypicker')
    implementation project(':amazon-maps-api-v2')
    releaseImplementation project(':tourguide')
    debugImplementation project(':tourguide')
    releaseImplementation project(':fullscreenimageslider')
    debugImplementation project(':fullscreenimageslider')
    implementation files('libs/libphonenumber-7.2.5.jar')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    implementation('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
        exclude module: 'answers-shim'
    }
    implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch-processor:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'


    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.6.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-livequery-android:1.0.3', {
        exclude group: 'com.parse', module: 'parse-android'
    }
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.18.5"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:gcm:1.18.5"
    //implementation "com.parse:parse-android:1.16.7"
    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:ktx:1.18.5"

    implementation 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.0.1'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.4.0',{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'gridlayout-v7'
    }
    implementation 'com.zhy:flowlayout-lib:1.0.3'
    implementation 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:5.+',
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'gridlayout-v7'
    }
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:5.+'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.25'

    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-android-support:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-http-cache:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.philliphsu:bottomsheetpickers:2.4.1' ,{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'gridlayout-v7'
    }
    implementation group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-android', version: '1.24.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.apollographql.android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: did you add android.useAndroidX=true & android.enableJetifier=true in gradle.properties?

Comment: yes, weirdly they were there by default.

Comment: RenderScript is broken, and is causing the issue. I've tried now to target 18 and 21 as previously but both do not work...

Comment: Did you try [this stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781821/renderscript-broken-with-androidx)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sso.techie! So yeah the issue is/was render script... I I did the same as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781821/renderscript-broken-with-androidx) link. But I had to build compatibility around renderscript, because this solution does not work pre API 23 anymore. I'm still hoping to find a solution using a newer support version of renderscript